# unable to retrieve modelandview object in jsp

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, web-applications

I'm unable to access model and view object from spring controller to jsp. I'm using spring 4,jstl 1.2 and webapp version 3.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"           xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
```

Here is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/products",method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ModelAndView processProductPage() {
    ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView();
    mv.setViewName("products");

    List<Product> products=productPageFacade.execute();//Retrieve products from db

    mv.addObject("products",products);
    mv.addObject("hello","hai");


    return mv;
   }
```

I'm able to get list of values from database but the objects added are not getting printed in jsp. For instance ${hello} is not getting printed but I'm able to retrieve ${i} value which is set in same jsp.

```
<c:set var="i" value="0" ></c:set>

<c:out value="${hello}"></c:out>yyy 
<c:out value="${i}"></c:out>
```

Taglib directive:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

I tried even using the following code but no luck.

```
HashMap<String, Object> map=new HashMap<>();
map.put("products", products);
map.put("hello","hai");     
mv.addAllObjects(map);      
return mv;
```

There is no issue in spring controller as I'm able to retrieve products object from db but the object added in model and view is not getting displayed in jsp.

Comment: Update I'm using tomcat 8 web server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how it got changed I used

```
org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView
```

instead of

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView
```

in my program which caused this issue. It got resolved by changing it back to servlet ModelAndView.

Answer (score 0):

`${hello}` is not printing because that is what you have named the attribute. Instead, you need to print the value, which is the second parameter of the `mv.addObject()` method.

```
<c:out value="${hai}"></c:out>
```